# Terraform - Each statement in the policy should have exactly one resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have an `aws_iam_policy_document` that Im trying to attach to multiple queues. The policy document looks like this:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "my_policy" {
  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "*"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }

    actions = [
      "sqs:SendMessage"
    ]

    resources = [
      "${aws_sqs_queue.q1.arn}",
      "${aws_sqs_queue.q2.arn}",
      "...",
      "${aws_sqs_queue.q8.arn}"
    ]

    condition {
      test = "ArnEquals"
      variable = "aws:SourceArn"
      values = [
        "${aws_sns_topic.sns_topic_name.arn}"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When I run terraform plan it does not show any error. However running terraform apply I get : `Policy is invalid. Reason: Each statement in the policy should have exactly one resource` . Is there a way I can put in a variable for the resource name which gets substituted with the name of the queue when being attached to said queue ?

This is how my queue and queue policy looks like:

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "queue_name" {
    name                       = "queue_name_${var.environment}"
    visibility_timeout_seconds = 30
    message_retention_seconds  = 345600
    max_message_size           = 262144
    delay_seconds              = 0
    receive_wait_time_seconds  = 0
}


resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "queue_name_policy" {
  queue_url = "${aws_sqs_queue.queue_name.id}"
  policy    = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.my_policy.json}"
}
```

Comment: Change principals  `type` to `AWS`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can put in a variable for the resource name which gets substituted with the name of the queue when being attached to said queue?

Terraform has a loop iteration mechanism using the [`count` meta-parameter](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#meta-parameters).

I have not used this much and I'm presently unable to actually *test* the code below, so with a small disclaimer that I could be wrong, I think this should work:

```
variable "number_of_queues" {
  default = 3
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "queue_name" {
  count = "${var.number_of_queues}"
  name  = "queue_name_${count.index}"
  // Other properties omitted
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "my_policy" {
  count = "${var.number_of_queues}"
  statement {
    resources = [
      "${aws_sqs_queue.queue_name[count.index].arn}",
    ]

    // Other properties omitted
  }
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "queue_name_policy" {
  count = "${var.number_of_queues}"
  queue_url = "${aws_sqs_queue.queue_name[count.index].id}"
  policy    = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.my_policy[count.index].json}"
}
```

You might have to use the [`lookup()` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#lookup-map-key-default-) instead of the square brackets – not sure.

Comment: `Lookup`  is for `maps`, your bracket syntax is correct. Useful:  `${aws_sqs_queue.queue_name}"` is a list of resources, you can get a single resource's `arn` by index `aws_sqs_queue.queue_name[0].arn` You can get a list of `arn` for all the resources using splat: `aws_sqs_queue.queue_name.*.arn` and also access that by index `aws_sqs_queue.queue_name.*.arn[0]` Is `count` on `aws_iam_policy_document` necessary, when `resources` block could reference the list of arns directly?  e.g. `    resources = [
      "${aws_sqs_queue.queue_name.*.arn}",
    ]` and likewise the queue policy?